# How to check if TV stream is working by PHP

Tags: php, stream, television

Is it possible to read something from UDP stream like this

```
udp://@220.155.228.45:1432
```

to check if it works?

IP here is fake but I tried this code on the IP and port that I know working but it failed:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock, '220.155.228.45', '1432') or die('Could not bind to address');
```

And what mean @ in address? Without @ players like VLC Media Player cannot read stream.